# Azure : VM fails to connect after being promoted as domain controller

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, rdp

I have few VMs provisioned on Azure, one of them acts as a read only domain controller replicating from a in house domain controller through site-to-site VPN.

The problem is every time I create a VM, promote it as read only domain controller, it runs well for few days or less then I fail to connect to it and get the message below

*The remote computer that you are trying to connect to requires Network Level Authentication (NLA), but your Windows domain controller cannot be contacted to perform NLA. If you are an administrator on the remote computer, you can disable NLA by using the options on the Remote tab of the System Properties dialog box.*

I fail to connect even using local admin account of the machine.

Any idea how to solve this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Configure the DNS servers for your virtual network. The VNET DHCP server is updating the network with the default Azure DNS instead of your active directory servers.

Here's the full guide:

[Install a replica Active Directory domain controller in an Azure virtual network](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-install-replica-active-directory-domain-controller/#reconfigure-dns-server-for-the-virtual-network)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem :(

Comment: Then you did something wrong. All your VMs should use your AD servers in DNS settings. Also, make sure to restart the Virtual Machine to apply the new configuration and that the DNS servers are actually accessible to the running VMs.

Comment: I was aware that I have to restart the server and I did restart them. I am sure that the DNS servers are accessible, I have other VMs on the same Virtual Network within same subnet that can see our local DNS.

Comment: Go to the new portal, select your VM, try "Reset Remote Access" button or navigate All Settings -> Troubleshoot -> Read resources